# Equation to calculate t-statistic (independent samples)

Tags: t-test, mean, simulation, independence, t-distribution

I am looking to simulate the t-distribution from first principles.

In particular, I want to understand how the distribution arises by comparing the mean of sample A of size $n_A$ (taken from population A) with the mean of sample B of size $n_B$ (from a distinct population B). Note that $n_A$ and $n_B$ are not necessarily equal.

The null hypothesis ($H_0$) of a t-test (independent samples) states that both samples come from the same population. I'm interpreting this as population A essentially being the same as population B.

To simulate the t-distribution, this is my plan (Python):

1. create a large (N=10000) array of normally distributed values with a mean $10$ and standard deviation, $2$. It will be one population because the null hypothesis assumes that the samples indeed come from the same underlying population.
2. iterate 1000 times as follows:

   - take a random sample of 20 elements (sample A), and another 10 elements (sample B) from the underlying population
   - calculate the t-statistic for this realisation of samples
   - record the t-statistic from each i$^\mathrm{th}$ iteration
3. plot a histogram of all 1000 t-statistic scores

However, point (2b) is where I have difficulty - **what is the equation to calculate the t-statisitc?** I have found various resources on the interweb (re-arranged slightly), but they don't appear to be entirely consistent.

[Shoffma5](https://www.slideshare.net/shoffma5/t-test-for-two-independent-samples) (slide 16)
$$t = \frac{\mu_A - \mu_B}{\sqrt{ \frac{1/n_A+1/n_B}{\nu} }}\frac{1}{\sqrt{ s_A^2\big(n_A-1\big) + s_B^2\big(n_B-1\big) }}$$

[ucdavis](http://psc.dss.ucdavis.edu/sommerb/sommerdemo/stat_inf/tutorials/ttesthand.htm) and [statisticshowto](http://www.statisticshowto.com/independent-samples-t-test/)
$$t = \frac{\mu_A - \mu_B}{\sqrt{ \frac{1/n_A+1/n_B}{\nu}}}\frac{1}{\sqrt{ \Big(\sum A^2 - \frac{(\sum A)^2}{n_A}\Big)^2 + \Big(\sum B^2 - \frac{(\sum B)^2}{n_B}\Big)^2 }}$$

where $\mu_A$ and $\mu_B$ are the respective means of samples A and B, and $s_A^2$ and $s_B^2$ are the respective variances.

**What is the correct equation to use to calculate the t-statistic (independent samples)?**

Comment: 1. While the two formulas should be algebraically equivalent, *don't* use the second formula, since it's numerically unstable. 2. Your simulation is somewhat flawed. The only way you can have an actual normally-distributed parent population is if that population is infinite. 3. When simulating populations with equal variances, there's little point doing simulations having $\sigma\neq 1$, since any other choice is equivalent to scaling both $\sigma$ and the difference in means (e.g. $\sigma=2$ and $\mu_1-\mu_2=4$ is the same as $\sigma=1$ and $\mu_1-\mu_2=2$ for given sample size)

Comment: Thanks for the response Glen. 1 - can you expand on 'numerically unstable'? 2 - Sure, I get that the normal distribution is theoretical in nature since is it based on an infinite population; I was merely hoping to approximate infinity by taking a 'large' population which, for the illustrative purposes of the simulation, is good enough. 3 - fair point.

Comment: (in reverse order) 2. but it's *much* easier to do an exact infinite-population simulation quite directly.   1. See discussion in comments here:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/210483/whats-up-with-this-variance-computation



See the answer here, which explains what the problem is:

https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/235004/is-it-possible-to-have-pearson-correlation-coefficient-values-1-or-values-1/235054

See also some of the comments under this answer:
https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/235143/805

...ctd

Comment: ctd... and these wikipedia links:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loss_of_significance and

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variance#Formulae_for_the_variance ... you should not implement those mean of squares minus square of means forms on a computer. If you need a fast one-pass algorithm, you can find mentions of them at some of the above links (though a search for *one pass variance* should hit something)

Comment: Just going back to the question "what is the correct equation for the t-statistic?", can I point you in the direction of another of my questions? If you feel you could provide some input there, that would help me very much. See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/294725/so-many-ways-to-calculate-the-t-statistic-is-this-the-super-formula-i-need-t