Mathematical formula for interaction term in multiple regression with two predictors
I am trying to understand the math behind the coefficients in a multiple regression with two predictors and their interaction. I know that this can be done in matrix notation OR directly in any statistical software, but I want to understand how to use correlations to set this up.
I will use the mtcars dataset from R as an example here:
model 1: lm(data=mtcars, mpg ~ hp + wt)

In this case, we get the equation as mpg ~ 37.22727 + -0.03177 hp + -3.87783 wt
I am able to use the correlations between the three variables as follows to produce these estimates using the formulas:
$$
b_{hp} = \frac{s_{mpg}}{s_{hp}} \frac{r_{hp,mpg}-r _{wt,mpg}*r_{hp,wt}}{1-r_{hp,wt}^2} = -0.03177
$$
$$
b_{wt} = \frac{s_{mpg}}{s_{wt}} \frac{r_{wt,mpg}-r _{hp,mpg}*r_{hp,wt}}{1-r_{hp,wt}^2} = -3.87783
$$
$$
a = M_{mpg} - b_{hp}M_{hp} - b_{wt}M_{wt} = 37.22727
$$
where $M$ stands for means and $s$ stands for standard deviations of the respective variables.
What I want to do is obtain the coefficients in a similar manner when there is an interaction between hp and wt in the model as below:
model 2: lm(data=mtcars, mpg ~ hp + wt + hp:wt)

How do I calculate the coefficients in this case? I tried to create a product term $hp*wt$ and got as far as calculating all the pairwise correlations (between $mpg$, $hp$, $wt$, and $hp*wt$) but do not know how to proceed from there.
Ultimately, I want to compute the coefficients returned by R to yield the following equation:
mpg ~ 49.80842 + -0.12010 hp + -8.21662 wt + 0.02785 hp:wt


Welcome to CV, Alice.  This is no different than any regression with three variables.  It's pointless to pursue non-matrix formulas: as the number of variables grows, they rapidly explode in complexity and provide no further insight.  The matrix formulas answer your question.  There are many ways to carry them out.  There's one given at https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/352130/, for instance.
